What does "on" mean here?
The chew "on" these cookies is very pleasant.
Let's see what he cooked up "on" this stew.
What does "on" mean in these sentences?

It's a prepositional villain https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/of  It indicates a relation between "the chew" and "these cookies" and you should understand from context. So it means "on" in the sense of "the chew on these cookies".

The OED has sense: 11.25.a:  "With reference to, as regards; concerning, about".

@BillyKerr That would normally be "a book on sailing" rather than "the chew on a cookie",

This isn't a "standard" use of "on", nor a common sense of "chew"  The speaker is conceiving the chew (=chewiness) as being an additional feature that the cookies might or might not have and so seems to have chosen "on".  The metaphor is that the "chew" is something added; you'd say "the icing on the cookies". The speaker is imagining "the chew" to be like "icing" in some figurative way.
The choice of preposition is rhetorical - a deliberate choice that contradicts reality to express a deeper idea.
For the second example, it could be the same, it could just be a mistake, or it could be the use of "on this stew" to refer to a place or time, as you would say "on this occasion".
If you are translating, don't feel the need to use the same preposition. It's normally impossible to translate isolated examples of non-standard language, since it just looks like a mistake by the translator.
